# Why is Illustrator adding whitespace around my artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm struggling for a while with the whitespace Illustrator is creating around my prints.

For example I've set the artboard to be this size:

[image]

But when I've saved my print as an eps it is always this big:

[image]

I know there is an option to save as web and then to uncheck 'Clip to artboard' but I really need to save it as an EPS.

Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Do you have any extra elements that could be forcing the EPS to be adding more space?

Answer (score 1):

It might be because, besides the blue circle and copy, there are other shapes in your art either filled with white, with no fill or transparent. When Illustrator tries to save the EPS, it is making sure all the shapes are saved.

To trim the EPS tight to the artboard width you could try this. When you select "Save As", tick "Use Artboards" in the "Save As" window and enter the number of the artboard you want to save in the Range input (enter 1 if there is only one artboard).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As cockypup said, EPS will show everytthing including what is outside the artboard. Making a clipping mask should also solve the problem. Make an unfilled and unstroked rectangle the same size (and position) as your artboard and place on top of your artwork. Select all and then go to Object/Clipping Mask/Make... or CMD-7(Mac) or CTRL-7(Windows).